# libimobiledevice wants to remove all my other packages

Tags: apt

When running the command `sudo apt-get remove libimobiledevice2` I get:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED: ... gdm gdm-guest-session gnome-power-manager gnome-session gnome-session-bin gvfs-backends indicator-power indicator-session kde-plasma-desktop kde-standard libgpod-common libgpod4 libimobiledevice2 nautilus-share ubuntu-desktop upower`
```

Is it really nessecary to remove all of my KDE and Gnome packages?

The source of the problem is that the installed oneric package doesn't recognize my ios 5.1 - so I wanted to switch to the latest and greatest (1.0.7 and if that's not good enough I'll go to the dev version 1.1.2).

I'm using oneric 64bit.

Comment: Are you using any PPAs for this? Why not just the upgrade to the new version, do you really need to remove this one before upgrading the package?

Comment: There's no packages for the version for oneric so I downloaded the tar and wanted to uninstall before I make install

Comment: When I tried to uninstall libimobiledevice I encountered the same message. I accepted it and then after the uninstall process was finished I restarted my laptop and it wouldn't boot.
I had too backup, uninstall, and reinstall my operating system(Ubuntu 20.04).
So be extra cautious with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the original problem (lib didn't work with iPhone iOS 5.1) by re-installing the libimobiledevice2.